# Problema al instalar Mayavi 4.5 en una distribucion Anaconda3 de 64 bits sobre Windows 8.1

Tags: python, conda, anaconda

Tengo un problema al instalar Mayavi 4.5 sobre la versión de 64 bits de Anaconda3 (en la de 32 bits no da un solo problema). Tras instalar Anaconda3, mediante:

```
conda install -c menpo mayavi=4.5.0
```

instalo Mayavi. Todo parece funcionar bien hasta que a la hora de linkar los paquetes:

```
Linking packages ...
An unexpected error has occurred, please consider sending the            |   0%
following traceback to the conda GitHub issue tracker at:

    https://github.com/conda/conda/issues

Include the output of the command 'conda info' in your report.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\flop\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\flop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 120,
in main
    exit_code = args_func(args, p)
  File "C:\Users\flop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 130,
in args_func
    exit_code = args.func(args, p)
  File "C:\Users\flop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", li
ne 78, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'install')
  File "C:\Users\flop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 40
7, in install
    execute_actions(actions, index, verbose=not args.quiet)
  File "C:\Users\flop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\plan.py", line 599, in e
xecute_actions
    inst.execute_instructions(plan, index, verbose)
  File "C:\Users\flop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\instructions.py", line 1
35, in execute_instructions
    cmd(state, arg)
  File "C:\Users\flop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\instructions.py", line 7
8, in LINK_CMD
    link(state['prefix'], dist, lt, index=state['index'])
  File "C:\Users\flop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\install.py", line 1092,
in link
    if not run_script(prefix, dist, 'post-link'):
  File "C:\Users\flop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\install.py", line 550, i
n run_script
    subprocess.check_call(args, env=env)
  File "C:\Users\flop\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 576, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\flop\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 557, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\flop\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\flop\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
```

Incluso si quiero crear un entorno virtual para instalar posteriormente Mayavi 4.5, tras crearlo e intentar activarlo me aparece el siguiente error:

```
C:\Users\flop\Anaconda3\Scripts>activate mientorno
".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

Agradecería cualquier sugerencia.Muchas gracias.

Comment: Eso parece más un problema de [tag:conda] que de `mayavi`. ¿Puedes instalar otras cosas usando [tag:conda]?

Comment: Si,si. Todo lo demás que he instalado con conda ha funcionado correctamente. De ahí mi duda, porque hasta hace poco el soporte de Mayavi para Python 3 era "experimental".

Comment: Nuevamente he desinstalado todo lo relativo a Python del ordenador, instalado Anaconda3 en el ordenador. Y al intentar con Mayavi...de nuevo el error.

Comment: ¿El mismo error que en la otra pregunta que abriste?, ¿todas las demás dependencias se te instalan correctamente? Prueba con [tag:pip]. Descarga [esto](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/dp2ng7en/mayavi-4.5.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl) y desde la misma carpeta donde se ha descargado el *.wheel* abre un *cmd* y escribe `pip install mayavi-4.5.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` a ver si así funciona.

Comment: No, el error no era el mismo. De ahí que generase una nueva pregunta. La buena noticia es que haciéndolo como me indicas, con pip...¡ha funcionado por fin!. Ya lo intenté con anterioridad pero sin éxito, supongo que porque aún no había desinstalado cosas y me daba problemas de compatibilidad. Pero con conda 64 bits, desde cero, he intentado varias veces instalar Mayavi 4.5.0  sin éxito. ¿Debo deducir de ello que el paquete conda para 64 bits de Mayavi 4.5.0 aún no está del todo maduro? Porque la versión de 32 bits va como la seda.

Comment: La versión de conda no es oficial, es de voluntarios, en este caso *mempo*, que se dedican a crear paquetes conda para que otros los podamos usar ;-) Lo mismo sucede con la versión para `pip` que he enlazado, se encarga Christoph Gohlke. Por tanto, kudos para ellos!!!!!

Comment: ¡Por supuesto que si,sin duda!. Muchas gracias Kiko por tu tiempo y por ayudarme con tu sapiencia.¡Un abrazo!.